# Adding to mapping rather than completely remapping

Tags: vim

I'm working on a plugin to allow bracket completion (I know it's available, it's more of a learning exercise).  To properly implement it, I need to add to the backspace mapping.  However, as it's an important key, I'd rather keep the existing functionality and just add to it rather than reimplementing the functionality.  The steps would basically be when in insert mode and press backspace, execute the original backspace key, then check for some conditions and maybe remove more characters.

I've tried something like `imap <backspace> <backspace><call_func_here>`, but that doesn't seem to work.  Again, I know I could remap backspace to just the function and try to recreate the backspace functionality, but I'd prefer to not do that.

Is this possible in vim?

Comment: Is backspace something provided by your plugin? Or do you mean insert an actual backspace?

Comment: Pressing backspace while using the plugin will execute the actual backspace (delete a char) then check if what was deleted has a closing char and delete that as well if there's nothing between the pair.  I think what I can do is to map it to a function which then calls unmap, calls backspace, then does work, then sets the mapping back.  Going to try that shortly

Comment: Honestly. I have no idea what you're trying to do. But `exec "normal! \<BS>"` should execute backspace without mappings.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to do is the following:

```
inoremap <silent> <BS> <BS><C-o>:call MyFunction()<CR>
```

- `inoremap` allows to create a non recurrent mapping in insert mode (it is often a good idea to use `nore` in your mappings). [`:h :inoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:inoremap)
- `<silent>` precise that the mapping will not be echoed on the command line (You will not see `:call MyFunction()` in the command line) [`:h :map-silent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:map-silent)
- `<BS>` is the reference to the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key that you want to remap.
- The second `<BS>` is here to issue a backspace in insert mode
- `<C-o>` switches to normal mode for only a command. [`:h i_CTRL-O`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O)
- `:call MyFunction()` is the call to your function the way you would do it in normal mode.
- `<CR>` correspond to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key which validate the call to your function.